# GPUImage animated gaussian blur filter

Tags: objective-c, gpuimage

I was using the GPUImage gaussian blur filter to blur a still image. I want to tie the blur size to an UI element and as the element is changed by the user I blur the picture. The way I am doing it right now is to change the blurSize when there has been a significant (> 0.25) change, reapply the filter and animate the new image into the imageView.

Is there a more efficient way for me to be doing this?

On the iPhone 5, while performance is not laggy, it is not super smooth either (but perhaps that is because this operation is simply too expensive to be super smooth).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

interesting question. Your best bet is to pre-compute and render CGImages at a couple of blur scales in your range, then use two stacked UIImageViews, with the one on top showing the blurrier copy but partially transparent. For example, if you rendered blurred at radiuses 1,2,3,…,10, and you wanted to show 3.7, you'd show image 3 on the bottom and image 4 on the top, at 70% opacity.

```
// Created in answer to Nikhil Varma's question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18804668/gpuimage-animated-gaussian-blur-filter
#import "GPUImage.h"
#define BLUR_STEP 2.
@interface AHViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat blurRadius;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;
@property (nonatomic, strong) GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter *blurFilter;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSCache *blurredImageCache;
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t blurQueue;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableSet *blurAmountsBeingRendered;
@end

@implementation AHViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ph.jpg"];
    self.blurFilter = [GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter new];
    self.blurredImageCache = [NSCache new];
    self.blurQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Image Blur Queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    self.blurAmountsBeingRendered = [NSMutableSet set];
    self.blurRadius = 1.0;
}
- (IBAction)sliderDidMove:(UISlider *)sender {
    self.blurRadius = 10 * sender.value;
}
-(void)setBlurRadius:(CGFloat)blurRadius {
    _blurRadius = blurRadius;
    CGFloat smaller = self.blurRadius - fmodf(self.blurRadius, BLUR_STEP);
    [self asyncGenerateImageWithBlurAmount:smaller];
    CGFloat larger = smaller + BLUR_STEP;
    [self asyncGenerateImageWithBlurAmount:larger];

}
-(UIImage *)cachedImageWithBlurAmount:(CGFloat)blur {
    return [self.blurredImageCache objectForKey:@(blur)];
}
-(void)asyncGenerateImageWithBlurAmount:(CGFloat)blur {
    // This image is already available.
    if([self.blurredImageCache objectForKey:@(blur)]) {
        [self imageIsAvailableWithBlur:blur];
        return;
    }
    // There's already a render going on for this. Just return.
    if([self.blurAmountsBeingRendered containsObject:@(blur)])
        return;

    // Start a render
    [self.blurAmountsBeingRendered addObject:@(blur)];
    dispatch_async(self.blurQueue, ^{
        self.blurFilter.blurSize = blur;
        UIImage *result = [self.blurFilter imageByFilteringImage:self.image];
        [self.blurredImageCache setObject:result forKey:@(blur)];
        [self.blurAmountsBeingRendered removeObject:@(blur)];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self imageIsAvailableWithBlur:blur];
        });
    });
}

-(void)imageIsAvailableWithBlur:(CGFloat)blurAmount {
    CGFloat smaller = self.blurRadius - fmodf(self.blurRadius, BLUR_STEP);
    CGFloat larger = smaller + BLUR_STEP;

    UIImage *sharperImage = [self cachedImageWithBlurAmount:smaller];
    UIImage *blurrier = [self cachedImageWithBlurAmount:larger];
    if(sharperImage && blurrier) {
        if(![self.imageView.image isEqual:sharperImage])
            self.imageView.image = sharperImage;
        if(![self.imageView2.image isEqual:blurrier]) {
            self.imageView2.image = blurrier;
        }
        self.imageView2.alpha = (self.blurRadius - smaller) / BLUR_STEP;
    }
}


@end
```

Comment: A better solution would be to avoid using a UIImageView as the output destination for the blurred image. There's a lot of overhead in extracting a UIImage from the framework, and a similar amount in assigning it to a UIImageView. Instead, the blur should be rendered directly to a GPUImageView so that all of this stays on the GPU. That's a much faster route.

Comment: Brad, first of all great work on your library! I am using UIImageView because the UIImages are stored in the NSCache and crossfaded back and forth. GPUImage is only run once per blur "tick" (BLUR_STEP), and the results are interpolated using imageView2.alpha (until/unless the NSCache evicts the resulting UIImage due to memory pressure).

Comment: @AdlaiHoller Thanks for the detailed code snippet. My question is, why are we using the stacked image view approach? Does having a 70% opaque  4 on top of 3 make the blur more realistic (even though that is a subjective term)?

Comment: @BradLarson I am going to try using the GPUImageView classes since I really want to optimize this section for speed and fluidity. Awesome library by the way (though I'm sure countless others have already told you that).

Comment: @NikhilVarma The stacked imageView approach lets us approximate blur amounts that we haven't computed. Say the user set the slider to 3.71. If we've already saved blurred images at 4 and 3, we can show them both blended together really quickly, rather than computing a whole new blurred image. If the user then drags to 3.72, we just change the mixing ratio. Brad is mistaken – GPUImageView simply cannot achieve fluidity here, because Gaussian Blur is extremely expensive.