# Interactive blurring of UIImage and UIView like iOS 8 spotlight

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiblureffect

iOS 8 introduces some pretty snazzy interactive blurring. Most notably, there's the interactive blur when you pull down for spotlight, but there's also the animation when opening and closing Siri (though that's not interactive). I've only noticed this interactive blur in one other place: the official Twitter app when pulling down on a profile view (parallax header image zooms and blurs *sometimes*).

I've attempted to animate something basic with a UISlider with both CoreImage and GPUImage (based on the answer to [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16277716/gaussian-blur-an-uiimageview-ios) and also Apple's [**UIImage+ImageEffects**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17536404/1214800), but nothing seems appropriately performant enough to animate the blur interactively (i.e. blurring an image to a single value works quickly once, but not at a framerate fast enough to blur continuously).

**How can I implement these methods in a way that they are performant enough to both blur and unblur a UIImage (and ideally a UIView or CIContext snapshot) interactively?**

Comment: Take a screenshot of your view, then blur the screenshot.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942037/blur-screen-with-ios-7s-snapshot-api

Comment: @NickWilkerson keyword here is **interactively**. Both the posts I linked to are doing exactly that, but they aren't performant enough unless running in GCD dispatch_async, and then it's not thread safe.

Comment: How about precalculating the frames (with different levels of blur if I understand your question correctly) before starting your animation, so that you have them available in memory during the animation?

Comment: @goldmine interesting idea... animate with what, CAKeyFrameAnimations?

Comment: Yes. I worked on something like this previously to produce a glowing button (lightening up in a sinusoidal fashion and repeating). I used CAKeyFrameAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"] and provided an array of timestamps with [animation setKeyTimes:times] and an array of UIImages with [animation setValues:values].

Comment: As discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18804668/gpuimage-animated-gaussian-blur-filter , you can kinda cheat on this by blurring the background, then animating a crossfade between the blurred image and the original sharp one. That gives you interactive performance without having to manage varying blur radii at each step.

Comment: @BradLarson yeah, tried that too and it's just not as "BAM!" beautiful

Comment: found this on reddit, might be what you're looking for http://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/2jjuec/how_does_apple_achieve_the_slidedown_blur_effect/

Comment: @akaralar wow that's crazy - it actually looks like it works. I'll have to give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple and one way of doing it, but it's definitively doable if you follow following steps and optional ways:

1. Most important: downsample the image. Basic resolution is not very important for gaussian blur. If you downsample only to half resolution, the amount of data is down to quarter!
2. Define end target blur radius.
3. Retrieve the architecture of device with the help of C functions and use different values of delta saturation parameter for different architectures, according to processing power, of course.
4. Experiment creating the blur with Apple provided library with radius step regarding to step value of parameter that is interacting with (KVO to `contentOffset` property, for example). dispatch_async and don't forget to callback with blurred image to main queue!
5. Methods above will almost for sure cater all the architectures from arm7s onwards, but you might still have some issues with arm7 - iPhone 4s).
6. If you still have issues, like with mentioned arm7, then double the `contentOffset` change required to make next blur with next radius. Then instead of changing the image property on UIImageView, rather create new UIImageView with new blurred UIImage and fade in alpha channel from 0 to 1 within the period the next blurred page is being created.
7. You might use number of tricks, like creating all blurred images one after another for the full interactive scale and cache them in collection and use them in method described in point 6.

There a also many other techniques if the animation is not interactive, but rather timed in the certain frame.